# How would I increment by one through each audio resource with the given loop?

Tags: java, android

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        numbersList.add((new Numbers("" + i, R.raw.)));
    }
```

let's say I have 100 audio files named "1.mp3","2.mp3","3.mp3"... and so on. How do I go about adding each sound file to each of my numbers?

Comment: you mean files named as "1.mp3" or as "one.mp3" ?

Comment: I meant "1.mp3"

Answer (score 2):

If resource name is **1.mp3, 2.mp3** etc then Use **getIdentifier(resource name,resource type,package name)** for get resource dynamically.

```
numbersList.add(getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(i+1), "raw", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: for the first argument "i+1" its saying that this is not a String..How would I go about getting around this?